# List item will go second column automatic and container space will also increase

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build navigation which will be vertical. Navigation's outer width will be fixed and when the item will be increased then other items will go to the next column.
I tried it with `flexbox` and added `flex-wrap: wrap;` in the container. But cant design this.

[image: When list item will in one column]
[image: When items will be increased]

I tried with these codes.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 320px;
  width: 80px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px
}

.item {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background: #efefef;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `width: 80px;` give `width: auto` or do not provide `width` at all. When the number of items increases touches to the bottom of the container it will be added to the next column. 
You do not have control over the container with here. You should make it flexible with auto width.

Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 320px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background: #efefef;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `auto` width do not solve it... see the *red* background (`container`) must cover the *items* :)

Comment: the `container` should cover the items, but should take the *auto* width of the *wrapping* flexbox - **that** is the requirement of OP....